# Finding out Roots for Dynamic Voltage Divider using Numerical Methods

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, roots, numerical-calculus, bisection

I Need to list all numerical methods that can be applied on Dynamic Voltage Divider Equation. Then select three methods (from open bracket or close bracket or combination of both) and compare their result in MS Excel.

I am unable to find a proper equation or problem regarding DVD to find roots from. Anyone who can provide an equation or problem from which roots can be found using numerical methods e.g. Bisection, Newton Raphson, False Position etc.

[image: The Problem I found is Here]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: It can be any circuit RC or RLC. I found an equation f(R) = e^(-Rt\2L){cos [sqrt((1\LC)-(R\2L)^2)t]}-q\q0 for RLC circuit(I have added circuit above) where I have to find f(R) using numerical methods. Here values of L,C,t are given but can you tell me what is q\q0 in it?